# Check dictionary exist in string

Tags: c++, dictionary, opencv

I have dictionary is vector string, and long string may contain text in dictionary or not. And my work is find which text in dictionary exist in long text. But the problem is have to be fast. That mean i can't check every text in dictionary.

```
cv::Mat query_descs = extract_features(inputText, listKeyWrongChar);
Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = DescriptorMatcher::create(DescriptorMatcher::FLANNBASED);
std::vector< std::vector<DMatch> > knn_matches;
matcher->knnMatch(query_descs, dataWrongWords, knn_matches, 50);
for (size_t k = 0; k < knn_matches.size(); k++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
        string prefecture_ = wrongWords[knn_matches[k][j].trainIdx];
        listResult.push_back(prefecture_);
    }
}
```

My solution im using is DescriptorMatcher:

- First I mark character in dictionary with index
- Then i create matrix with row is each text in dictionary, and column is character
- I create matrix like that with long text
- Then I use DescriptorMatcher to find text closest to long text.

The problem that it have many wrong word. And sometime word i need it out of 50.

Can anyone help me with this problem ?

Comment: [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) might help.

Comment: look like trie take a lot of time because i have to check every character in my long text

Comment: I don't see how you could avoid to check every characters of your long text... With `Trie`, you should only multiply complexity by `O(1)` for that part. (And complexity to construct the Trie is linear in total number of characters of the dictionary). It seems to me it is an optimal solution about complexity.

Comment: This question probably needs improvement, or I am entirely misunderstanding it. Are you seriously using `FLANNBASED` K-Nearest neighbor matching on a dictionary of words? No wonder that is slow and inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

Seem `Trie` is a good solution. Survey time handle seem to be faster than my solution